# Adjusting Batch read size using Teradata as a Source in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was wondering if anyone had a chance to use Teradata as a Source and if so do you know if we can set batch read size for it? I am currently connecting to an on-prem Teradata and was hoping to improve performance to move files to a blob storage account by adjusting batch size on the Teradata source side.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch write size  is the property which is on the sink side and if I understand that you are reading the data from Terradata which is the source . I think you are looking for a Read Batch Size property which to my understanding does not exist at this time .

But I think since Terradata support TOP N in the query , you can loop through all the records with that , by reading top n records at a time .

I am not Terradata literate , but I think we can achieve this in SQL .

Comment: Hi @HimanshuSinha-msft thank you for the update. I will take a look at the TOP N query. The reason I avoided using query in the source is that I wanted to take advantage of parallel Hash property that ADF allows.

Do you know if read batch size is supported in other sources? For example Azure DB to Azure DB or Oracle to Azure DB? Is that only for DB sources or does blob and storage gen2 support that as well?